# Is there a simple way to parse comma separated Key:Value pairs in Excel, Power Query or VBA if the values contain unescaped commas?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, powerquery, m

I'm working with a CSV export of identity data containing ~22000 records. One of the fields included is titled 'ExtendedAttributes' and each cell in the column contains a quote bound string of comma separated Key:Value pairs. Each record in the file has an arbitrary number of extended attributes (up to around 50). My ultimate objective is to expand these extended attributes into their own columns in Excel (2016). I already have solutions for the expansions into columns from other data using formulae, simple VBA and most recently Power Query based approaches.

However, my previous solutions have all been based on the Key:Value pairs being simple to delimit. In this export, the ExtendedAttributes field has:

1. Value data that may contain unescaped/unquoted commas. e.g.

   `"Key1: Value1, name: surname, forename, Key2: Value2, ... "`
2. Keys that may contain multiple comma separated values, which are also unquoted/unescaped. e.g.

   `"Key1: Value1, emailAlias: alias1@domain, alias2@domain, alias3@domain, Key2: Value2, ... "`

My usual approach to this, where Key:Value pairs don't have these problems would be to delimit using commas to break it into the key value pairs, transpose the data into rows, then delimit using the colon to populate my new columns and their values as described [here in the PowerBI community pages](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Extracting-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-into-multiple-columns/td-p/381676)

This doesn't work here because delimiting using a comma breaks the values.

Is there a straightforward way to parse this into the constituent Key:Value pairs using (ideally) Power Query? Happy to also go with VBA or formula based solutions.

My instinctive approach would be to try and identify substrings containing a colon and prepend them with a unique character, which can then be used as a delimiter. (It's not impossible that the data may also include unescaped colons, but I'm happy to assume that it doesn't) But recognise that this may be a needlessly complex approach and I'm unsure how best to do it.

I'm happy to keep values with multiple comma separated items as a single unit (A problem for me to deal with later).

For the example data:

```
"Key1: Value1, name: surname, forename, emailAlias: alias1@domain, alias2@domain, alias3@domain, Key2: Value2, ... "
```

I'd like to end up with something that lets me treat the data like this, using maybe a ! as an example unique character that I could then use as a delimiter:

```
"Key1: Value1!name: surname, forename!emailAlias: alias1@domain, alias2@domain, alias3@domain!Key2: Value2!..."
```

I don't have access to the original data (vendor controlled system) and have limited data processing tools on my corporate desktop (Excel 2016, VBA, PQ).
Appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "unescaped commas"? Isn't he csv a comma delimited type? If yes, you you want meaning that inside a delimited comma are there other commas? I couldn't find such an example in what you presented... Now, supposing that we'll clarify the issue, how to you like returning in the way you show us, for all 22000 records? Rows, or records? Is it a record = a row? But independent of that, do you like transposing the rows (with comma separated items) on a single column?

Comment: What happens if you try opening the csv file in Excel? I think, a good idea should be to edit your question and place two relevant pictures: The first one with some (relevant) lines of the csv file and a second one with what you want accomplishing after processing it...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to be able to delimit the string into its constituent Key:Value pairs which I can't do because some of the values have commas in them. So using a comma to delimit breaks up the values. I'm already able to handle the transposing once it's correctly delimited. Opening the CSV file in Excel correctly puts the 'ExtendedAttributes' field into a single column. Each cell in the column contains the strings of Key:Value pairs I describe in the question. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Can you share a relevant part/slice of the csv file in discussion? Of course, having the necessary comma delimiter and the comma in between, too. Is it any logic to be applied in order to determine which such commas are not delimiters? How do you appreciate, like human, this aspect?

Comment: Like I say in the question, the string contains Key: Value pairs. The keys are identified because they have a colon at the end of them. Everything afterwards is a Value until the next substring with a colon at the end of it, which is the next Key.

Comment: Now i think I understood better. Can you share a slice of such a file? I would like to make some tests with it, if possible. You can share it on a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share because it's confidential corporate data, but the examples above are identical in form to the real data. Each record has up to 50 key:value pairs in the ExtendedAttribute column.

Comment: Now, if your example is identical with the real data row, the csv looks not being a comma separated type. Are there spaces after comma (", ") as you show us? How the row is ending? In `vbCrLf`, or are there other caracter before end of lines?

Comment: You're correct - it's not properly formed CSV data in the ExtendedAttribute field, which is the problem. Everything outside the ExtendedAttribute field is properly formed CSV data and handled fine by Excel. Inside the ExtendedAttribute field the entire string is surrounded by quotes and the commas have spaces after them.

Comment: But do you need processing only that, so named by you, "ExtendedAttribute field" area? If so, can you easily separate it from the rest of the file? If not, how the rest of the file does look? An algorithm to globally process the file, must take that part in consideration, too.

Comment: Very hard to tell with the limited examples you have presented. But it appears that your keys are characterized by a single word followed by a colon. If that is always the case, you can split using that characteristic.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's correct. The 'Keys' are a word followed by a colon. So ideally I'd like to prepend those with a unique character that I can then use to delimit the string correctly. If I delimit using a colon then I lose the key name to the end of the preceding value. Apologies that my question wasn't worded clearly enough to explain this.

Comment: Didn't you find some time to test the code I posted? Can you find a kind of 'marker' in the rest of the file to differentiate it against the discussed area? Should it be missing of any colon character? Or something else...

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm testing your example code now. Thank you for taking the time to produce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power Query, you can define a function `Partition` as follows:

```
let
    Output = (str as text, sep as text) as text =>
    Text.RemoveRange(
        Text.Replace(
            Text.Combine(
                List.Transform(
                    Text.Split(str, " "),
                    each if Text.Contains(_, ":") then sep & _ else _
                ),
                " "
            ), ", " & sep, sep
        ),
    0, Text.Length(sep)
    )
in
    Output
```

**Example text transformation using separator `!`**

Starting text:

```
Key1: Value1, name: surname, forename, emailAlias: alias1@domain
```

1. Split the string based on spaces into a list

```
Key1:
Value1,
name:
surname,
forename,
emailAlias:
alias1@domain
```

2. Prepend any list items containing `:` with separator `!`

```
!Key1:
Value1,
!name:
surname,
forename,
!emailAlias:
alias1@domain
```

3. Combine the list back into a string

```
!Key1: Value1, !name: surname, forename, !emailAlias: alias1@domain
```

4. Replace `, !` with `!`

```
!Key1: Value1!name: surname, forename!emailAlias: alias1@domain
```

5. Remove the first separator

```
Key1: Value1!name: surname, forename!emailAlias: alias1@domain
```

Once you have this function defined, you can call it in a column transformation that would look something like

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Prev Step", {{"ColName", each Partition(_,"!") , type text}})
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. Thank you. With this I've been able to identify and drill down to problematic data (Colons in the values etc) and tweak and extend your code to incorporate more specific patterns. I expected about 50 unique Keys. My original approach gave me ~1000 mostly bogus ones. Using several iterations of your code it's down to ~100 which is much more manageable. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say anything about the file records not being counted in the "ExtendedAttribute field" category... I prepared a function able to separate that area which you put in discussion. Please, use the next code:

```
Function separateKeys(x As String, sep As String) As String
  Dim arr1, arr2, i As Long, k As Long
  
  arr1 = Split(x, ": ")
  ReDim arr2(UBound(arr1))
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr1) - 1
    If arr1(i + 1) = arr1(UBound(arr1)) Then Exit For
    arr2 = Split(arr1(i + 1), " ")
    arr2(UBound(arr2) - 1) = Replace(arr2(UBound(arr2) - 1), ",", sep)
    arr1(i + 1) = Join(arr2, " ")
  Next
  separateKeys = Replace(Join(arr1, ":"), sep & " ", sep)
End Function
```

The above function can (probably) be adapted in a way to skip calculations for rest of the file, or also transform each comma in the `sep` character (simple using `Replace`).

In order to test the above function, please use the next testing `Sub`:

```
Sub testSepKeys()
  Dim x As String, sep As String
  
  sep = "|" 'you can try something else, but improbable to appear in the processed text
  x = "Key1: Value1, name: surname, forename, emailAlias: alias1@domain, alias2@domain, alias3@domain, Key2: Value2, Value3, key3: Val1, Val2"
  Debug.Print separateKeys(x, sep)
End Sub
```

Like global way of working, I would suggest splitting the file on line separator, then process all the array elements (lines) using the above (adapted) function and finally join it on the line separator.
The newly created file should be open using `Workbooks.OpenText`, `DataType:=xlDelimited`, `OtherChar:=sep`.

Please, test the above function and send some feedback.

Comment: This code works on the handful of example strings I've thrown at it! Thank you. I'll incorporate it into my existing workflow probably by looping through the extended attributes column and replacing the contents in situ. I'll let you know if it's fixed the 'real world' problem. :) It's a shame excel doesn't have more elegant mechanisms for handling pattern matching problems like this.

Comment: @crutchley: When you are talking about a **column** what do you mean? I was imagining only rows... Where this column should be? In the csv file? Do you intend processing it after opening in Excel? Did you think to the process I recommended when I tried talking about a 'global way of working'? Did you get my point? It can be easily put in practice and I can do it, but without knowing how to separate the 'attributes' area from the rest of the file, I am missing an important point which  cannot overpass...

Comment: @crutchley: But separated of what I mentioned above, do you consider that my code did not answer your question?

Comment: The column is the one containing the 'ExtendedAttributes' data with the problem. The rest of the CSV file is properly formed and the opens in excel in its own columns. I understand your point about the general way of working, but for my specific task I'm going to loop through each row in the 'ExtendedAttributes' column and apply your function to the contents of each cell. I'll do that between meetings this afternoon. I upvoted your answer but because I've only just signed up it doesn't show my upvote. As soon as I've applied your fn to my data I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @crutchley: No need of up vote... But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. Our main goal here is to help people and make them learning. This thread can be seen by many users in the future...